# Change default input date placeholder

Tags: html

So I have this input button with the default state that has no date chosen (no value), but I don't like the way it stays, so instead, I would like the date format with a text for example `Select Date`.

[screenshot for the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJHNQ.png)

Comment: I tried placeholder, but nothing

Answer (score 1):

I created 2 events and added some css styling to achieve the desired result.

The events are:

`focusIn`

- sets type to `date`

`focusOut`

- Changes type to `text`
- if the user didn't select date then show 'Select date'

```js
function init() {
    const el = document.querySelector('#date');
    el.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => {
        event.target.type = 'date';
    });
    
     el.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
        event.target.type = 'text';
        if(!event.target.value) {
          event.target.placeholder = 'Select date';
        }
    });
}

addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
#date {
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  outline: none;
}

#date:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder='Select date' class="textbox-n" type="text" id="date">
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor check my updated answer.

Comment: Good job. Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```html
<input placeholder="Select Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="date">
```

Comment: But when you click it it resets

Comment: @bohokep350 i don't understand what you mean ?